# T4MVC handling minified js and css files generated with Chirpy

Tags: asp.net-mvc, t4mvc, chirpy

I am using T4MVC and the Chirpy plugin in an ASP.Net MVC 3 website and I am loving both of them. Only T4MVC can't seem to handle the minified js files generated with Chirpy and .yui.js javascript files.
Chirpy is generating .min.js files but the default T4MVC script expects .yui.min.js.

I have made the following adjustments to T4MVC to make it work
In **T4MVC.tt.settings.t4**  I have added

```
const string ChirpyJSExtension = ".yui";
```

And in **T4MVC.tt** on line 983 I have changed the code in

```
if (!ExcludedStaticFileExtensions.Any(extension => projectItem.Name.EndsWith(extension, StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase))) {
    // if it's a non-minified javascript file
    if (projectItem.Name.EndsWith(".js") && !projectItem.Name.EndsWith(".min.js")) { 
        if (AddTimestampToStaticLink(projectItem)) { #>
    public static readonly string <#=Sanitize(projectItem.Name.Replace(ChirpyJSExtension,string.Empty))#> = T4MVCHelpers.IsProduction() && T4Extensions.FileExists(URLPATH + "/<#=projectItem.Name.Replace(ChirpyJSExtension,string.Empty).Replace(".js", ".min.js")#>") ? Url("<#=projectItem.Name.Replace(ChirpyJSExtension,string.Empty).Replace(".js", ".min.js")#>")+"?"+T4Extensions.TimestampString(URLPATH + "/<#=projectItem.Name#>") : Url("<#=projectItem.Name#>")+"?"+T4Extensions.TimestampString(URLPATH + "/<#=projectItem.Name#>");
        <#+} else {#>
    public static readonly string <#=Sanitize(projectItem.Name.Replace(ChirpyJSExtension,string.Empty))#> = T4MVCHelpers.IsProduction() && T4Extensions.FileExists(URLPATH + "/<#=projectItem.Name.Replace(ChirpyJSExtension,string.Empty).Replace(".js", ".min.js")#>") ? Url("<#=projectItem.Name.Replace(ChirpyJSExtension,string.Empty).Replace(".js", ".min.js")#>") : Url("<#=projectItem.Name#>");
        <#+}  #>          
<#+}
    // if it's a non-minified css file
    else if (projectItem.Name.EndsWith(".css") && !projectItem.Name.EndsWith(".min.css")) { 
        if (AddTimestampToStaticLinks) { #>
    public static readonly string <#=Sanitize(projectItem.Name)#> = T4MVCHelpers.IsProduction() && T4Extensions.FileExists(URLPATH + "/<#=projectItem.Name.Replace(ChirpyJSExtension,string.Empty).Replace(".js", ".min.js")#>") ? Url("<#=projectItem.Name.Replace(ChirpyJSExtension,string.Empty).Replace(".css", ".min.css")#>")+"?"+T4Extensions.TimestampString(URLPATH + "/<#=projectItem.Name#>") : Url("<#=projectItem.Name#>")+"?"+T4Extensions.TimestampString(URLPATH + "/<#=projectItem.Name#>");
        <#+} else {#>
    public static readonly string <#=Sanitize(projectItem.Name)#> = T4MVCHelpers.IsProduction() && T4Extensions.FileExists(URLPATH + "/<#=projectItem.Name.Replace(ChirpyJSExtension,string.Empty).Replace(".js", ".min.js")#>") ? Url("<#=projectItem.Name.Replace(ChirpyJSExtension,string.Empty).Replace(".css", ".min.css")#>") : Url("<#=projectItem.Name#>");
        <#+}  #>          
<#+}
    else if (AddTimestampToStaticLink(projectItem)) { #>
    public static readonly string <#=Sanitize(projectItem.Name)#> = Url("<#=projectItem.Name#>")+"?"+T4Extensions.TimestampString(URLPATH + "/<#=projectItem.Name#>");
<#+}
    else { #>
    public static readonly string <#=Sanitize(projectItem.Name)#> = Url("<#=projectItem.Name#>");
<#+}
} #>
```

I hate editing included scripts like this but I saw no other solution.

So does anyone have a better solution for this that leaves the default T4MVC script alone?

Comment: I think Wayne Brantley (http://twitter.com/#!/waynebrantley) had made most of the changes relating to this, and may have comments on it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

New version of chirpy solve this problem.
http://chirpy.codeplex.com/SourceControl/changeset/changes/ab7715fabba6